# How do I make my systemd service run via specific user and start on boot?

Tags: systemd

I just upgraded from Ubuntu server 14 to version 15. I had trouble getting my upstart script working after the upgrade, and read that systemd is the new default. I'm far from a linux expert, so please go easy on me :-)

Here is what my upstart script was before:

```
description "NZBGet upstart script"

setuid robert
setgid robert

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

expect fork

script
    exec nzbget -D
end script

pre-stop script
    exec nzbget -Q
end script
```

Based on the [upstart to systemd wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), I used the tables provided there to map things as closely as I could in my new systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=NZBGet Service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/nzbget -D
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/nzbget -Q
Restart=on-failure
```

This file is located at `/home/robert/.config/systemd/user/nzbget.service`. To start the service manually, I've been doing:

```
$ systemctl --user start nzbget
```

This works great. However, when I log out of my SSH session, the service shuts down. Also, it does not start on bootup or user login. I want it to behave the same as it did as an upstart service: I want it to start at boot, run constantly, and as a specific user.

What do I need to do to get this configuration?

Answer (score 299, accepted):

### First problem

You can specify the directives `User=` and `Group=` in the `[Service]` section of the unit file.

### Second problem

To make the service run on boot, you should not put it in your home folder. Instead, put it under `/etc/systemd/system/`. This is the folder meant to be used by the system administrator (i.e. you) to add new system-wide services.

Other folders include:

- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` is meant for packages that want to install unit files, though under Debian and Ubuntu the folder is actually `/lib/systemd/system/` because the various `bin` and `lib` folders have not been merged into a unified `/usr/` prefix yet.
- `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/` is for installing units by locally compiled packages.

### Testing the unit

Once the unit file is in an appropriate location, you can try starting the unit immediately by typing `systemctl start <UNIT_FILENAME>` as usual. It should work without having to type the unit's full path. The extension also doesn't have to be specified if it's `.service`.

### Enabling the unit

Before you can enable your unit, you need to add an `[Install]` section, under which you should add the directive `WantedBy=multi-user.target`. This directive specifies the stage of the boot-up process during which the service should be started (if it were enabled). `multi-user.target` is appropriate for most services.

Once that information is added, you can use `systemctl enable <UNIT_FILENAME>`, which enables the unit, making systemd from now on automatically start it during boot up at the specified stage.

Comment: This worked. I had to specify the absolute path to the service filename in the `systemctl enable` command though, this was not obvious to me at first. Also enabling gave me some warning about a missing `[Install]` section. I ignored it, but I'm not sure if it will impact its ability to start at boot time.

Comment: The `Install` warning was actually really important. It won't start on boot without `WantedBy=multi-user.target` under the `[Install]` section. After adding this to the `.service` file, *then* you can `enable` it.

Comment: I apologize about leaving the answer unattended for such a long time. I fixed the location where the unit file should go, added the missing information about the `[Install]` section. Hope it's now more helpful for anyone looking for it.

Comment: This becomes much easier when the username is templated, i.e. your service is defined with a filename in the format `something@.service` then `enable`d like `something@username.service` the setting becomes `User=%i` meaning the user is not hard-coded and multiple users can use the same definition. [An example.](https://github.com/joeroback/dropbox)

Comment: Will it start if I put it under `/etc/systemd/user/` ?

Comment: Your unit files belong in `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system` and you run `systemctl enable [service]`, which links them into `/etc/systemd/system`. You're not *supposed* to drop files in `/etc/systemd/system`. See: `man systemd` and look under **DIRECTORIES**

Comment: @fbicknel - according to Arch distro that's not correct: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User  "`/etc/systemd/user/` **where system-wide user units are placed by the system administrator.**"  (not that there is necessarily a universal truth value here ... I would just like to do it in the most straightforward way for myself)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all this correctly. 1. I got an app installed as non root that I'd like to autostart as specific technical user vs root. Where do I place the .service file and where and how do I tell the system to call systemctl start on boot as that user vs. root? 2. I would like the technical user to start/stop the app using systemctl. I assume changing the permissions of the /lib/systemd/system/ dir is not the right way to go? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Regarding "_To make the service run on boot, you should not put it in your home folder._": This is wrong; it is fine for a Unix user `robert` to have a user service `nzbget.service` located at their `~/.config/systemd/user/nzbget.service`. `robert` can then enable this service with `systemctl --user enable nzbget`.

Answer (score 108):

You might be interested in using systemd's [user lingering](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html#enable-linger%20USER%E2%80%A6) functionality. It is enabled via `loginctl enable-linger USERNAME`.

It causes a separate service manager for the respective user being started at boot, so your user-defined units in `~/.config/systemd/user` will be picked up and processed at boot and shutdown times according to your service configuration.

You can also use `systemctl --user` for managing and configuring the service(s), which will operate on your user's service manager, not the one of the system.

Comment: `systemctl --user` is a fantastic finding. Thanks!

Comment: @byteborg Maybe you can contribute to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409900/user-lingering-systemd-dependency-on-postgresql? I need dependency on PostgreSQL in user lingering service, but database remains system service, not user's one.

Comment: Once the services are running, is there any techniques that can allow the user to see the logs of the service?  An unprivileged user wouldn't be able to get to /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Note that `systemctl --user` doesn't seem to work for SSH sessions though.

Comment: @MarkKCowan it does, you only have to make sure you can run it. In some instances you might get the error `systemd[29239]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_systemd.so): /lib/security/pam_systemd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and `PAM adding faulty module: pam_systemd.so` when doing `systemctl start user@$USER.service` in that case just install `libpam-systemd` and you'll get that working and starting at boot

Comment: @mpr have a look at journalctl, unprivileged users can run that.