# Make service monit possible for a particular user to start without prompting for password on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: policykit

I want to run monit as another user on Ubuntu 16.04, but it keeps prompting for a password. Seems policykit is new on Ubuntu 16.04. How could I put this service into the ignore authentication list?

My goal is that user1 would be able to run `service monit start` and `service monit stop` without getting a prompt for password.

Running it as root is not an option

```
user1@serverabc.uk:~$ service monit start
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'monit.service'.
Authenticating as: root
Password: 

polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start monit.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status monit.service' for details.
user1@serverabc.uk:~$ 
user1@serverabc.uk:~$ systemctl status monit.service 
* monit.service - LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/monit; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2017-06-30 11:30:51 GMT; 6h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/monit; bad; vendor preset: enabled) <- this line showing it's using init.d old file instead of new type of service file, so I can't just edit service file and point it to specific user.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I make my systemd service run via specific user and start on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/676007/119531).

Comment: not really, if you check the last couple lines, it shows the config actually using /etc/init.d/monit, not the new type of service file

Comment: guys, read carefully on my question, it's not using new systemd init file

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution!

Add a file, `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/monit.pkla` with these contents

```
[monit service]
Identity=unix-user:user1
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Now user1 can start monit without problems

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot.