# Make a systemd service run as user xyz

Tags: systemd

I've created a `.service` file that includes `User=xyz` in the `[Service]` section.  The service still runs as root.  Quid?

```
[Unit]
Description=...
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java ...
Type=simple
ExecStop=/usr/bin/java ...
User=siraprise

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Check this issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot I was able to get an answer for a similar question here.

Comment: Look man, the only thing that other issue tells me is that I can put User=xyz in the [Service] section of my .service file.  Which, if you read my question (and I mean ***attentively***) , is something I clearly already knew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the behaviour changes if User= is specified before ExecStart=.

Don't know whether that's a feature or an accident, but as a feature it's pretty dumb and moreover it seems undocumented which is actively annoying.

Comment: Did you file a bug report?

Comment: No.  Where should I do that ?  Systemd ?  Ubuntu ?  Kubuntu (which is the flavour I am actually using) ?

Comment: that's totally weird