# How to run "systemctl" + $ + "apache" $=stop,start,restart as non sudo/root user?

Tags: sudo, debian, visudo

Yeah basically the title,
I want to do that things from a app that can run Linux scripts per SSH.
I only want to run these three and not ALL from systemctl with my basic user.

So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Cmnd_Alias` in `/etc/sudoers` like:

```
Cmnd_Alias APACHEADMIN = /usr/bin/systemctl start apache2, /usr/bin/systemctl restart apache2, /usr/bin/systemctl stop apache2
```

Then add a line for the user privilege:

```
jsmith  ALL = NOPASSWD: APACHEADMIN
```

Comment: Hey man thanks, but it doesnt work. I still get the Info to do this thing as sudo/root. I think I need the rights for the Service that i will change too, or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `--user` switch. From `systemctl(1)`

> ```
> --user
>
> Talk to the service manager of the calling user, rather than the
> ```

service manager of the system.

You may follow the instruction of this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/859583/790920).