# Start a program before logging in?

Tags: login, login-screen

I have a desktop and a laptop, both running ubuntu 20.04 for what it's worth.

The desktop in the office has a network card compatible with Wake On Lan, so sometimes I will be in the living room and power it on, ssh into it, and do some stuff.

However, there are a couple of applications that won't start until I have logged in the desktop enviroment (like the megasync utility or a application called PostyBrib that requires a gui to launch).

Is there any way to launch a program before logging in so that, once you log in, they are already there and running? Ideally without having to ssh into the machine to launch them so I can just turn it on and let it do it's preprogrammed jobs on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can always start a service, and set it to be owned by you (your user name), see:

- [How to run a Linux Program on Startup](https://timleland.com/how-to-run-a-linux-program-on-startup/)
- [How do I make my systemd service run via specific user and start on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot)