# Systemd user service not starting automatically

Tags: 20.04, systemd, services

This has been asked many times in some form or another but none of the advice seems to have helped.

I want to run syndaemon after I login to the GUI, but I always have to start it manually

```bash
$ systemctl --user status syndaemon.service
● syndaemon.service - Syndaemon Service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/tastywheat/.config/systemd/user/syndaemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
$ systemctl --user start syndaemon.service
$ systemctl --user status syndaemon.service
● syndaemon.service - Syndaemon Service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/tastywheat/.config/systemd/user/syndaemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-04-11 00:33:54 CDT; 3s ago
   Main PID: 5032 (syndaemon)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/syndaemon.service
             └─5032 /usr/bin/syndaemon -i 0.8 -R -t -k
```

It doesn't appear that there was any attempt to start the service either (it only shows here because I started it manually).

```bash
$ grep -ir syndaemon /var/log/syslog
Apr 11 00:33:54 xtrnmntr systemd[1068]: Started Syndaemon Service.
```

I also followed advice regarding the use of `loginctl enable-linger`.

```bash
$ find /var/lib/systemd/linger/
/var/lib/systemd/linger/
/var/lib/systemd/linger/tastywheat
```

And I tried an alternative method of modifying `logind.conf`.

```bash
$ grep -ir tastywheat /etc/systemd/logind.conf 
KillExcludeUsers=tastywheat
```

Also my user-service, in case that's at fault:

```bash
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/syndaemon.service 
[Unit]
Description=Syndaemon Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/syndaemon -i 0.8 -R -t -k

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I guess I don't mind if I have to move this service into `/etc/systemd` but I didn't want to have to use `sudo` every time I tweaked this or some other user service.

Comment: Try this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364126/160267 and this: https://askubuntu.com/a/859583/459561

Comment: I make something like this (something sould be start with my desktop session) with a desktop file in `$HOME/.config/autostart`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The appearance of my username in `/var/lib/systemd/linger/` should be proof that `loginctl enable-linger USER` was applied. I added `RequiresMountsFor` but no change.

Comment: To make a long story short you are trying to disable the touchpad when you are typing on the keyboard so your palm(s) are interpreted as mouse clicks or moves?

Comment: Not sure `mkdir $HOME/.config/environment.d/`   Put a file in it with suffix .conf and following content `DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: I have the similar issue now with Ubuntu 22.04. @TastyWheat, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @ywiyogo I didn't quite "solve" the issue. I used the workaround of placing a desktop file in my `~/.config/autostart` directory.